# Oauth 2.0 scope implementation for Implicit grant in java

Tags: java, oauth-2.0

I'm planning to implement OAUTH 2.0 to secure my REST apis. During the course i was able to secure my api using accessToken. If request doesn't have accessToken, he will be redirected to User register page and once he has accessToken then only he will be allowed to access api. But my problem is with "Authorization" i.e I'm not getting how exactly "scopes" help to redirect specific application.I'm asking for any references to scope implementation.

ex: admin can access student,staff data.
student can access only student data.
 How is this achieved using scope. Any reference to scope implementation would be appreciated. Everywhere they have said what scope can do , but no where is the mention of how. Let me know if any clarification is required.